# Apache Camel: XMLJSON conversion for empty tags to strings instead of arrays

Tags: json, apache-camel, json-lib

When using the Camel XMLJSON library and when converting an XML message to JSON using the unmarshal option. The application is converting the empty tags to empty JSON arrays. Is there a way to override this behavior to instead convert it into empty strings.

For example

```
<person>
<first_name>john</first_name>
<last_name/>
</person>
```

converts to

```
{
"first_name": "john",
"last_name": []
}
```

instead of the below

```
{
"first_name": "john",
"last_name": ""
}
```

How can this default behavior be overridden to provide the second output

Comment: I suggest to look at the net.sf.json-lib:json-lib library and see what they say about this kind of conversion, as Camel uses that for the conversion.

Comment: The problem is that it is not obvious from the message if <last_name> indeed contains just a string value or further child elements, which is why it is resulted in a json object instead.