# Apache Camel: XML to JSON conversion

Tags: json, xml

I have an xml file like this:

```
<JsonPerson>
        <Id>1111</Id>
    <personInfo>
        <firstName>aaa</firstName>  
        <lastName></lastName>   
    </personInfo>
</JsonPerson>
```

I used xmljson tag in my route to change the format from xml to json and the output is like this:

```
 {
  "Id" : "1111",
  "personInfo" :
    {
    "firstName" : "aaa",
    "lastName" : [],
    }
  }
```

But my desire output is like this:

```
{
"Id" : "1111",
"personInfo" :
    {
    "firstName" : "aaa",
    "lastName" : "",
    }
 }
```

How do I accomplish that (without writing any extra java code)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also: [Apache Camel: XMLJSON conversion for empty tags to strings instead of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056627/apache-camel-xmljson-conversion-for-empty-tags-to-strings-instead-of-arrays)

Comment: grammar, typos, formatting as OP intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a dozen different ways of converting XML to JSON or vice versa, and none of them will consistently give the answer that you actually want: that's because your expectations typically depend on some understanding of the semantics of the data which you have but the software library doesn't.

It doesn't help that the XML fragment you have shown isn't a complete well-formed XML document; with only part of the input, we can only give you part of the solution.

If you want to do XML-to-JSON conversion with precise control my recommendation would be to use XSLT 3.0. Something like this:

```
<xsl:output method="json">

<xsl:template match="/*" priority="1">
  <xsl:map>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <xsl:map>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[*]" priority="2">
  <xsl:map-entry key="local-name()">
    <xsl:map>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:map>
  </xsl:map-entry>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*"  priority="3">
  <xsl:map-entry key="local-name()">
    <xsl:sequence select="string(.)"/>
  </xsl:map-entry>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I edited the codes in my question.

Comment: I've amended the answer accordingly. I've included three rules for three kinds of elements that occur in your input. Of course it will fail or do the wrong thing on other inputs, e.g. elements that have attributes, or elements that have multiple children with the same local name.